# How do you create a ConstUnsafePointer in Swift

Tags: swift

General question: I have an object which I want to convert to a ConstUnsafePointer. Everything I've tried seems to fail...how do I do it? I was able to do this previously in DP2, but cannot work it out in DP3.

Previously, I had code which looked like this:

```
var bpData = AUSamplerBankPresetData(bankURL: Unmanaged<CFURL>(_private: soundBankURL), bankMSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB), bankLSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB), presetID: presetID, reserved: 0)

let bpDataPointer: CConstVoidPointer = &bpData

// set the kAUSamplerProperty_LoadPresetFromBank property
result = AudioUnitSetProperty(samplerAudioUnit,
  UInt32(kAUSamplerProperty_LoadPresetFromBank),
  UInt32(kAudioUnitScope_Global),
  0, bpDataPointer, 8)
```

However, now CConstVoidPointer is no longer around and has been replaced by ConstUnsafePointer. The AudioUnitSetProperty method looks like this:

```
func AudioUnitSetProperty(inUnit: AudioUnit, inID: AudioUnitPropertyID, inScope: AudioUnitScope, inElement: AudioUnitElement, inData: ConstUnsafePointer<()>, inDataSize: UInt32) -> OSStatus
```

But, if I change CConstVoidPointer to ConstUnsafePointer<()> I get the error:

'inout AUSamplerBankPresetData' is not convertible to 'ConstUnsafePointer<()>'

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work in beta6: var bpData = AUSamplerBankPresetData(bankURL: Unmanaged<CFURL>(_private: soundBankURL), bankMSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB), bankLSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB), presetID: presetID, reserved: 0)

Comment: I posted a new answer with an update for beta 6. I asked this question beta 3 I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear necessary to have the intermediate pointer constant. You should be able to do this:

```
result = AudioUnitSetProperty(
    samplerAudioUnit,
    UInt32(kAUSamplerProperty_LoadPresetFromBank),
    UInt32(kAudioUnitScope_Global),
    0, 
    &bpData, 
    8)
```

The func has this definition:

```
func AudioUnitSetProperty(
    inUnit: AudioUnit, 
    inID: AudioUnitPropertyID, 
    inScope: AudioUnitScope, 
    inElement: AudioUnitElement, 
    inData: ConstUnsafePointer<()>, 
    inDataSize: UInt32
        ) -> OSStatus
```

This line:

```
inData: ConstUnsafePointer<()>,
```

Is translated from this C:

```
const void *            inData,
```

The `inData` parameter is a constant pointer to anything, which is what `ConstUnsafePointer<()>` means. I could not try this exact code within a Core Audio app, but I have gotten similar code to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry to take so long to get back to you. So, I tried this and this worked...but I don't understand why. It seems like if this is the case then `&bpData` should be of type `ConstUnsafePointer<()>`, so it doesn't make sense to me why the line: `let bpDataPointer: ConstUnsafePointer<()> = &bpData` throws an error

Answer (score 0):

In beta 6, it's changed again. Thankfully, this time it looks like the solution is here to stay and doesn't involve any C.

```
let description = AudioComponentDescription(componentType: OSType(kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice),
  componentSubType: OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_Sampler),
  componentManufacturer: OSType(kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple),
  componentFlags: 0,
  componentFlagsMask: 0)

let instrument = AVAudioUnitSampler(audioComponentDescription: description)

let soundBankPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "sf2")
let soundBankURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundBankPath!)

var error: NSError? = nil
instrument.loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL(soundBankURL, program: program, bankMSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB), bankLSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB), error: &error)
```

For my sf2 files, the program is usually 1 or 0. I'm not really sure what this refers to, and any help is appreciated. However, this should get you unblocked for your program with a little trial and error.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. That's an AVAudio solution - which I'm guessing will be the "standard" someday. Right now I want to play a generated MIDI sequence. AudioToolbox has MusicSequence and MusicPlayer for that. On the MusicSequence you can call MusicSequenceSetAUGraph to set the "sampler" aunode. AVAudioUnitSampler is not an aunode. Hence my attempt to create the augraph. I've tried the new AV MIDI Player too. Here's the problem with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550625/avmidiplayer-init-with-musicsequence Again, thanks for the response.